# Neo4j variable-length pattern matching tunning

Tags: neo4j

Query:

```
PROFILE
MATCH(node:Symptom) WHERE node.symptom =~ '.*adult male.*|.*151.*'
WITH node
MATCH (node)-[*1..2]-(result:Disease)
RETURN result
```

Profile:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/goQtM.png)

Problems:
There are over 40 thousand "Symptom" nodes in the database, and the query is very slow because of the part - "[*1..2]".

It only took 4 seconds when length is 1, i.e "[*1]", but it will take about 30 seconds when length is 2, i.e "[*1..2]".

Is there any way to tune this query???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly your query is using the `regex` operator, and it can't use indexes. You should use the `CONTAINS` operator instead :

```
MATCH (node:Symptom) 
WHERE node.symptom CONTAINS 'adult male' OR node.symptom CONTAINS '151'
RETURN node
```

And you can create an index :`CREATE INDEX ON :Symptom(symptom)`

For the second part of your query, as it, there is nothing to do ... it's due to the complexity you are asking to do.

So to have better performances, you should think to :

- put the relationship type on the pattern to reduce the number returned path : `(node)-[*1..2:MY_REL_TYPE]-(result:Disease)`
- put the direction on the relationship on the pattern to reduce the number returned path : `(node)-[*1..2:MY_REL_TYPE]->(result:Disease)`
- find an other way to reduce this complexity (filter on a property of the relationship , review your model, etc)

For your information, you can directly write your query in one step (ie. without the `WITH`, but in your case performances should be the same) :

```
MATCH (node:Symptom)-[*1..2]-(result:Disease)
WHERE node.symptom CONTAINS 'adult male' OR node.symptom CONTAINS '151'
RETURN result
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answering! I will try it !  :-)

Comment: That really helps !!! I've  created indexes and change regex to 'contains', the query is very faster !!! Thank you so much !!!

Comment: You're welcome ! And don't forget to accept the answer :)